# How to update group summed table data using Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Below is my update query:

```
UPDATE   (  SELECT   BTD_ITEM_CODE,
                 INVI_ITEM_CODe,
                 BTD_UOM_CODE,
                 INVI_UOM_CODE,
                 BTD_GRADE_CODE,
                 INVI_GRADE_CODE_1,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY) BTD_QTY,
                 SUM (INVI_QTY) INVI_QTY,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY_LS) BTD_QTY_LS,
                 SUM (INVI_QTY_LS) INVI_QTY_LS,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY_BU) BTD_QTY_BU,
                 SUM (INVI_QTY_BU) INVI_QTY_BU
          FROM            AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET
                       INNER JOIN
                          AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD
                       ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_SYS_ID =
                             AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_BTH_SYS_ID
                    INNER JOIN
                       OT_INVOICE_HEAD
                    ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_TXN_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_TXN_CODE
                       AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_NO =
                             OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_NO
                 INNER JOIN
                    OT_INVOICE_ITEM
                 ON OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID =
                       OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_SYS_ID
                    AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_ITEM_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_ITEM_CODE
                    AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_UOM_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_UOM_CODE
                    AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_GRADE_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1
      GROUP BY   BTD_ITEM_CODE, BTD_UOM_CODE, BTD_GRADE_CODE)
   SET   INVI_QTY = BTD_QTY,
         INVI_QTY_LS = BTD_QTY_LS,
         INVI_QTY_BU = BTD_QTY_BU
 WHERE       INVI_ITEM_CODE = BTD_ITEM_CODE
         AND INVI_UOM_CODE = BTD_UOM_CODE
         AND INVI_GRADE_CODE_1 = BTD_GRADE_CODE;
```

I need to update values in a detailed table `OT_INVOICE_ITEM` using values from `AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET`. The 3 values `BTD_QTY`, `BTD_QTY_LS` and `BTD_QTY_BU` needs to be summed as there are multiple transactions in the table. The unique identifier is `BTD_ITEM_CODE` in the both the detailed table. The transaction code and number is common for both the header tables `OT_INVOICE_HEAD` and `AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD`. The header and detailed tables for both the tables need to be joined as well. At last whatever summed values we get from `AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET` needs to updated to `OT_INVOICE_ITEM`.

I tried the above code but got error that `ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view`. I cannot understand why.

The `INVI_ITEM_CODE` should match with `BTD_ITEM_CODE`, `INVI_UOM_CODE` should match with `BTD_UOM_CODE` and `INVI_GRADE_CODE_1` should match with BTD_GRADE_CODE, then only records should be updated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if the below query helps -

```
            with t1 as 
  (  SELECT   BTD_ITEM_CODE,
                 INVI_ITEM_CODe,
                 BTD_UOM_CODE,
                 INVI_UOM_CODE,
                 BTD_GRADE_CODE,
                 INVI_GRADE_CODE_1,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY) BTD_QTY,
                 SUM (INVI_QTY) INVI_QTY,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY_LS) BTD_QTY_LS,
                 SUM (INVI_QTY_LS) INVI_QTY_LS,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY_BU) BTD_QTY_BU,
                 SUM (INVI_QTY_BU) INVI_QTY_BU
          FROM            AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET
                       INNER JOIN
                          AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD
                       ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_SYS_ID =
                             AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_BTH_SYS_ID
                    INNER JOIN
                       OT_INVOICE_HEAD
                    ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_TXN_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_TXN_CODE
                       AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_NO =
                             OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_NO
                 INNER JOIN
                    OT_INVOICE_ITEM
                 ON OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID =
                       OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_SYS_ID
                    AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_ITEM_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_ITEM_CODE
                    AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_UOM_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_UOM_CODE
                    AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_GRADE_CODE =
                          OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1
      GROUP BY   BTD_ITEM_CODE,
                 INVI_ITEM_CODe,
                 BTD_UOM_CODE,
                 INVI_UOM_CODE,
                 BTD_GRADE_CODE,
                 INVI_GRADE_CODE_1)
Update T1
   SET   INVI_QTY = BTD_QTY,
         INVI_QTY_LS = BTD_QTY_LS,
         INVI_QTY_BU = BTD_QTY_BU
```

Comment: `FROM AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET as A` gave an error so I removed `as A`, then again I got error in the line `update OT_INVOICE_ITEM Z` , that `ERROR line 25, col 5, ending_line 25, ending_col 10, Found 'update', Expecting: (  SELECT   -or-   ,`

Comment: I have edited the query further to account for a column (INVH_SYS_ID 
) that missing in the group by clause. Please let me know if it still causes an error

Comment: `update OT_INVOICE_ITEM Z` line gives error `ERROR line 25, col 9, ending_line 25, ending_col 14, Found 'update', Expecting: (  SELECT   -or-   ,`

Comment: Hi, I have reverted to using your original query but with minor changes. Please check

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on whether query validation failed or the update did not work?

Comment: there's error in the query near the line `update t1` . The error is `ERROR line 42, col 1, ending_line 42, ending_col 6, Found 'Update', Expecting: (  SELECT   -or-   ,`

Answer (score 0):

I got it accomplished by the following query, it is a very long and repetitive query but is there any optimized or short query to do that?

```
UPDATE   OT_INVOICE_ITEM
   SET   INVI_QTY =
            (SELECT   SUM (BTD_QTY) BTD_QTY
               FROM            AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET
                            INNER JOIN
                               AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD
                            ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_SYS_ID =
                                  AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_BTH_SYS_ID
                         INNER JOIN
                            OT_INVOICE_HEAD
                         ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_TXN_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_TXN_CODE
                            AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_NO =
                                  OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_NO
                      INNER JOIN
                         OT_INVOICE_ITEM
                      ON OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID =
                            OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_SYS_ID
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_ITEM_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_ITEM_CODE
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_UOM_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_UOM_CODE
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_GRADE_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1),
         INVI_QTY_LS =
            (SELECT   SUM (BTD_QTY_LS) BTD_QTY_LS
               FROM            AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET
                            INNER JOIN
                               AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD
                            ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_SYS_ID =
                                  AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_BTH_SYS_ID
                         INNER JOIN
                            OT_INVOICE_HEAD
                         ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_TXN_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_TXN_CODE
                            AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_NO =
                                  OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_NO
                      INNER JOIN
                         OT_INVOICE_ITEM
                      ON OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID =
                            OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_SYS_ID
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_ITEM_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_ITEM_CODE
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_UOM_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_UOM_CODE
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_GRADE_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1),
         INVI_QTY_BU =
            (SELECT   SUM (BTD_QTY_BU) BTD_QTY_BU
               FROM            AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET
                            INNER JOIN
                               AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD
                            ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_SYS_ID =
                                  AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_BTH_SYS_ID
                         INNER JOIN
                            OT_INVOICE_HEAD
                         ON AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_TXN_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_TXN_CODE
                            AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD.BTH_NO =
                                  OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_NO
                      INNER JOIN
                         OT_INVOICE_ITEM
                      ON OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID =
                            OT_INVOICE_HEAD.INVH_SYS_ID
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_ITEM_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_ITEM_CODE
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_UOM_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_UOM_CODE
                         AND AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET.BTD_GRADE_CODE =
                               OT_INVOICE_ITEM.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
Update OT_INVOICE_ITEM Z
   SET  ( INVI_QTY, INVI_QTY_LS, INVI_QTY_BU )   = ( 
WITH T1 as (
SELECT   BTD_ITEM_CODE, BTD_UOM_CODE, BTD_GRADE_CODE, INVH_SYS_ID,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY) BTD_QTY,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY_LS) BTD_QTY_LS,
                 SUM (BTD_QTY_BU) BTD_QTY_BU,

FROM      AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_DET A
INNER JOIN
          AA_BIN_TRANSACTIONS_HEAD B
ON        B.BTH_SYS_ID = A.BTD_BTH_SYS_ID
INNER JOIN
          OT_INVOICE_HEAD C
ON        B.BTH_TXN_CODE = C.INVH_TXN_CODE
AND       B.BTH_NO = C.INVH_NO

Group by BTD_ITEM_CODE, BTD_UOM_CODE, BTD_GRADE_CODE, INVH_SYS_ID
)
SELECT BTD_QTY, BTD_QTY_LS,
           BTD_QTY_BU
FROM   T1
WHERE (BTD_ITEM_CODE, BTD_UOM_CODE, BTD_GRADE_CODE, INVH_SYS_ID) =
(Z.INVI_ITEM_CODE, Z.INVI_UOM_CODE, Z.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1, Z.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID)
and exists
  ( Select 1
    From t1
    WHERE (BTD_ITEM_CODE, BTD_UOM_CODE, BTD_GRADE_CODE, INVH_SYS_ID) =
    (Z.INVI_ITEM_CODE, Z.INVI_UOM_CODE, Z.INVI_GRADE_CODE_1, Z.INVI_INVH_SYS_ID)
)
)
```